# Change Application Title (Color, Location, Font) -Wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Some apps I am using seem to have the text for the application title on the top instead of the bottom and even have like background behind the text([Whats cheaper](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/store/app/whats-cheaper/f4731705-63d9-4bd6-905e-16a3b1580ec7)) and I am wondering how to do that.

For the background text I thought it was static to the image but when I change my phone color it also changes that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your tile to support phone accent color just make it transparent.

And the only place system can put your app name is on the left botton side of the tile (see "Contoso" text on the example).

[image: tile example]

So, if you need something else just do not provide any text and draw an image.

```
var imageUri = DrawTileImage(); //here you should draw an image with transparent 
                                //background and any icons/text layout 
StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
{ 
       Title = string.Empty,
       BackgroundImage = imageUri,
};
```